# Constant Time algorithms for $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[x] / (f(x))$?

Tags: reference-request, finite-field, side-channel-attack

I want to implement some (lattice based) protocols to better familiarize myself with a programming language (Rust). These tend to do arithmetic over rings like $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, or "extensions" of this ring (meaning $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[x] / (f(x))$. Since it seems like I'll need to implement the ring arithmetic myself (there are finite field libraries, but this stops certain optimizations I am interested in exploring such as double-CRT arithmetic), I might as well do something slightly-more-than-naive, and use constant time algorithms (which I am assuming are quite well-known at this point).
I am somewhat interested in algorithms that assume special structure of $m$ and $f(x)$ (say $m = 2^k \pm c$ for small $c$, or $f(x)$ a cyclotomic polynomial), but my primary interest is of algorithms that make no special assumptions on the structure of $m$ or $f(x)$.

Is there a particularly good reference for these algorithms? [Chapter 14](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf) of *Handbook of Applied Cryptography* seems to be a good start. It doesn't appear to discuss polynomial arithmetic *directly*, but it seems like you could piece together something by using their MPI arithmetic section. Additionally, this chapter doesn't discuss *constant time* algorithms directly, but quickly glancing over their algorithms I don't see anything that is too obviously variable time.

Still, is there some better reference for the task I am interested in?

Comment: Joining the Rust wave.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a total answer (it does not discuss polynomial arithmetic), the [Big Integer Design](https://www.bearssl.org/bigint.html#fn5) section of the BearSSL page seems like a good resource to share on this problem. Many of the algorithms are roughly similar to those in chapter 14 of *Handbook of Applied Cryptography*, but care has been made to make them constant time (not all of the algorithms in chapter 14 are by default). In general BearSSL aims to be a "pedagogical" implementation of TLS. Practically speaking, this means it is well-documented, and algorithmic decisions seem to be explained well.

I have not yet looked into algorithms for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$, so won't accept an answer until I get to there (or someone else suggests references).